# Can I switch the 'connected' user within an sql script that is sourced by mysql?

Tags: mysql

I was wondering if I can switch the "connected" user within an sql script that is executed by `mysql`.

Here's a description of my goal. Perhaps, it's not necessary to swich the user and another solution gives me what I want.

I want to write a *database creation script* like so:

```
create databse some_db;

create user u@localhost identified by 'pw';

grant all on u.* to u;

-- Here's where I want to switch the user, but *obviously* the 
-- following command fails

connect u@localhost/pw;

-- Now, as new user, create the tables:

use some_db;

create table t (...
```

This script would then be called from the command line like

```
$ mysql -u root -p"....." < create_db.sql
```

Is this possible or do I have to leave the script in order to switch the connected user?

Comment: Why do you want to switch users mid-script? You gain nothing from doing that.

Comment: @Justin Maybe one user has CREATE DATABASE and GRANT privileges, but no CREATE TABLE, whereas another user only has CREATE TABLE.

Comment: @Shi I stand corrected, and slightly terrified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, you can not change the user in the middle of the script unless you create a brand new connection with the credentials of the other user.

BTW, connect command only reconnects but there are only two optional parameters as documentation states: db and host.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a regular way to switch the user from within an SQL script.

An irregular could be the usage of a [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-procedure.html) or the usage of [table triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html). Both allow setting a DEFINER. So you could try to put the "special user code" into a stored procedure or a trigger, call the stored procedure or trigger the trigger and get the code executed.

If even that does not work, you need one script:

```
#!/bin/sh -eu
mysql --host localhost --user root --password root_pw < create_user.sql
mysql --host localhost --user u --password pw < create_table.sql
```