# Mysql: Changing database user from within sql

Tags: mysql

What MySQL command could I use to set (and authenticate) a different user from within an SQL script? I can switch databases (with `USE otherdb`), but I can't find anything about changing the user as well.

Comment: The user is fixed throughout the lifetime of a connection or session. You need to make a new connection to act as a different user in MySQL.

Comment: Thanks... but can you cite a source to support this statement? There are MySQL extension commands for changing the database, character set, and isolation level, so why not the user?

Comment: maybe duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114621/can-i-switch-the-connected-user-within-an-sql-script-that-is-sourced-by-mysql

Comment: @Jungsu, that looks like the same question indeed, thanks! But still no definitive answer. (I could have given a "not as far as I know" answer myself :-))

Comment: @alexis Here is a post from official MySQL forum. See the next message in the thread. http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,234282